# React-native ScrollView scrollTo not working as it should

Tags: react-native

This is my function:

```
const scrollToDown = () =>
positionRef.current.scrollTo({x: -100, y: -100, animated: true});
```

When calling this function I want my screen to be scrolled a little bit down, but instead it is being scrolled all the way to top of the screen.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - how to scroll a ScrollView to a given location after navigation from another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680890/react-native-how-to-scroll-a-scrollview-to-a-given-location-after-navigation-f)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
    const scrollRef = useRef();

    const onPressTouch = () => {
        scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
            y: 100,
            animated: true,
        });
    }

    <ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
     ....
    </ScrollView>
```